# Launch another JVM from Java with proxy arguments

Tags: java, proxy, jvm-arguments

I'm writting a Java Launcher Program, that should display installed Java programs and launch them, if needed.

Therefore i use the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` method with `java.exe -jar myjar.jar` as argument.

This works so far, but i also need to pass custom proxy settings to the jvm. From the command line this is possible with:

`java.exe -http.proxyHost=www.example.com -http.proxyPort=80 -jar myjar.jar`

But if i run this command in java it states:

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: -http.proxyHost=www.example.com
```

So the question: Am i doing something wrong or is this not possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Runtime options should have a `D` at the beginning:

```
java.exe -Dhttp.proxyHost=www.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -jar myjar.jar
```